# facebook feed page plugin error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: facebook, facebook-feed

I am trying to display a simple facebook feed on a website using [page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/)
But I keep getting the following error. Does anyone know what it means? and perhaps any way to resolve it?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
at a (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:254:358)
at a.c._inlineJS (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:255:1551)
at b (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:255:1002)
at xyCIQCGmYe4.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:14:3616
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at j (xyCIQCGmYe4.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:14:3596)
at Object.appendContent (xyCIQCGmYe4.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:14:2032)
at Object.setContent (xyCIQCGmYe4.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:14:1880)
at b.<anonymous> (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:39:2329)
at ug (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:58919)
at Sj (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:118576)
at Rj (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:118136)
at Qj (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:117671)
at Ok (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:127937)
at Nk (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:127252)
at Ak (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:123724)
at Wf (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:52973)
at tk (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:120748)
at Object.enqueueSetState (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:59:59325)
at b.a.setState (Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:58:1753)
at Miz6oWqAvcL.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:39:2237
at AsyncRequest._dispatchResponse (x9ZrO_yAkJs.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:16:6351)
at Object.applyWithGuard (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:58:9980)
at AsyncRequest.c (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:58:10684)
at x9ZrO_yAkJs.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:15:84
at e (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:322:291)
at Object.applyWithGuard (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:58:9980)
at d (f1ExCm8DHSA.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz:296:2252)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug coming from their SDK code, in which case you can't do much but wait until they fix it. (You could check their bug tracker and see if it has already been reported.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the reply. When I change the page url to some other random page, there seems to be no problem. I am only getting this error for this particular facebook page.

Comment: Might be a page you can't embed then? Quote docs, _"You can use the Page plugin **for any Page that is not restricted,** for example, by country or age."_

Comment: I've had this error forever - and despite the console errors, the plugin seems to be functioning properly. Can't find the offending : in the script either, the line it references doesn't even have one. Still, I'd like to find a solution.

Comment: I am getting the same issue while using the above mentioned plugin. Anyone how know how to fix it?

Comment: @WaseemAnwar are you still able to view the feed on your website? My website has stopped showing the facebook feed completely, since just recently.

Comment: @KomalDhobe I can see the feed on mysite but still getting the error in browser console.

Comment: @WaseemAnwar I still dont know how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too and much like most responses, I was cracking my brain figuring where is the problem coming from. The source in console didn't really have any errors, but yet it reported as error.

After some detailed testing, I realized that if I include the `timeline` parameter in the tabs section, then I get this error. As soon as I removed it, the error disappeared. Probably the semicolon is coming from the feed or something. Might help someone else having this problem.